# $I=m r^2$, moment of inertia

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Why does moment of inertia dependent on square of radius and can this be derived by some means? If so then how? or only can be proved experimentally?

Comment: Hi Junior M. Welcome to Phys.SE. What definition of moment of inertia do you start from?

Comment: What is your starting point if asking for a derivation?

Comment: It’s a *definition*. The only sensible variant of your question is why is this a *useful* definition.

Answer (score 2):

Mass moment of inertia arises as the factor between angular momentum and rotational speed along the axis of rotation. $$ L = I\, \omega$$

You proceed as follows. The process is simplified somewhat to bring it down to a high school level.

Consider a rotating object of finite volume, where each infinitesimal particle of the object moves tangentially with velocity $v = \omega\,r$. The simplest arrangement is that of a ring or a cylinder where all the mass is arranged along the same radius $r$. Conceptually you are adding up all the little masses to come up with the total mass $$m = \sum \Delta m$$

The total angular momentum is found by the sum of the individual angular momentum $\Delta L = r \Delta p$, which itself is the product of radius and linear momentum $\Delta p = v \Delta m$

$$ L = \sum r\,(v \Delta m) = \sum r ( r \omega) \Delta m = (\sum \Delta m) (r^2 \omega) = \underbrace{ (m r^2)}_{\text{MMOI}}\, \omega$$

It means that for each particle, its distance to the rotation axis has an effect on MMOI in two ways. Once since the further away the particle is the faster the speed and hence higher momentum, and a second time since the momentum is located further away from this axis increasing its moment of momentum.

This is where the term moment in mass moment of inertia comes from. From the fact that angular momentum $r \Delta p$ is the moment of momentum (torque of momentum of sorts).

Answer (score -2):

It can be derived mathematically with integral calculus and this is a standard exercise in an elementary physics textbook.